# JobManager doesn't recover in HA mode

Tags: apache-flink

I have a Flink HA cluster with 2 job managers and a zookeeper quorum of 3 nodes.

My failed job manager didn't get recovered after I killed it.
Here is how I didn't it and what I've observed:

1. I started the HA cluster with start-cluster.sh
2. Job manager A got elected.
3. I killed job manager A with kill command.
4. Job manager B got elected.
5. Job manager B was working well.
6. But job manager A never recovered since then.

Do I miss something here or is it the case that HA cannot handle such failover(the flink instance gets killed directly)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The HA in standalone mode works exactly as you described, which means when current leader fails the stand-by jobmanager takes over.

Jobmanager in a standalone mode is just a java process that cannot spawn itself after shutdown, so you have to spawn it manually. You can also consider some other deployment mode e.g. YARN/Mesos/Kubernetes which ensures the processes will be restarted.